# Adding new installer class in windows application getting compiler error

Tags: installation, c#, .net-3.5

I have created a widows application with setup project. I compiled and build.Everything looks fine.

For changing the configuration file during installation am trying to add a new Installer file. when i add it by default i get the below code

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer : Installer
    {
        public Installer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

before modifying When i compile this Am gettin **Circular base class dependency involving 'windows_setup.Installer' and 'windows_setup.Installer'**

windows setup is the name space i used for the application

After that i changed the class name to

```
public partial class MyInstaller : Installer
```

Now am getting  **Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'windows_setup.Installer' is less accessible than class 'windows_setup.MyInstaller**

Why am getting this and how to resolve this...?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like `Installer` is not a public class.  If that is the case then you cannot have a class inherit it.

Comment: Did you use the rename refactoring or just manually edit the one file?

Comment: My mistake is when i initially created the file i named it installer as it sounds optimal. But saving it with any other name will not cause any issue. Initially i tried Renaming but got few errors after that i deleted and created the new installer with diff name. No issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `partial` class and you have two source files associated with the class.  You must change the second source file to use the MyInstaller class name.